# Specify which "view" to display in an ItemsControl in Prism upon startup

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I have a "mainregion" implemented using a Tab Control, with a few tab items. Attribute *ViewSortHint* affects the sorting of the tab items upon startup, but that's not what I want.

Upon startup, I want to read from a config file, and programmatically show a specific tab right off the bat. Is there a way to do this cleanly in Prism's architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

1.) I have an IConfigProvider (my own thing) instance passed in via Unity DI in the constructor of my *IModule*s (among others like IRegionManager, IUnityContainer). This configProvider, is just a dictionary passed around. It holds the last view name of the view retrieved upon startup (bootstrapper). In each of my views, when they are activated, they fire off a pubsub event telling any listener that subscribes to this PubSub event its name. In my case, the sole listener saves this in a config file.

2.) During IModule -> Initialize

```
 container.RegisterType(typeof(Object), typeof(TheViewClass), typeof(TheViewClass).FullName);
```

3.) I test the name (convention) of this module vs. the last view name in the configProvider.  If there's a match. I will also call:

```
RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(TheViewClass).FullName);
```

to navigate to it!!!

Hope this helps somebody.